# How to keep subtitles track while switching default audio track?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've video files with 2 audio tracks (eng,jap) and 1 sub track (eng), I was trying to change the default audio track using ffmpeg *(the default is English i want to make the Japanese is the default audio track)*

I found that command

`ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:1  -disposition:a:0 default -disposition:a:1 none -c copy "output.mkv"`

It worked fine, but then i found that the subtitle track is gone, so how can i keep it?

thank yuo

Answer (score 1):

Map all streams with `-map 0`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -disposition:a:0 default -disposition:a:1 none -c copy output.mkv
```

I'm guessing your input contains at least 4 streams (1 video, 2 audio, 1 subtitle) but you were only mapping 3 streams. `-map 0` will include all of the streams from the input.